# Find all movies released by the same studio

Tags: sql

I have a problem that has the following table:

```
Movie             Studio    Year    Rating
The Shining       Warner    1999     8.4
The Pianist       Warner    2002     8.6
The LOTR        Dreamworks  2004     8.7
License to Kill Dreamworks  2001     8.3
Complicated         HP      2005     7.7
Django Unchained    HP      2003     8.8
Diamonds        John Lewis  1997     6.7
```

How do you find all movies that have higher rating than all previously released
movies by the same movie studio?

So the output, I guess, should be: The pianist because it was released later than the other movie the shining, by the same studio and has a higher rating.
The LOTR for the same reason as above.

Django Unchained because although Complicated was released later it has lower rating than Complcated. It also happens to be the oldest movie from that studio so I don't know how to handle this.

Finally, Diamonds should be returned as it is the only movie from that studio and there is nothing to compare to.

Comment: If you want to return exactly one movie per studio you have to decide what's most important - the highest rated or the most recent movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from movietable t1
where not exists (select 1 from movietable t2
                  where t2.studio = t1.studio
                    and t2.rating > t1.rating
                    and t2.year < t1.year)
```

Will return a movie if the same studio has no older movie with a higher rating. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: are you sure about t2.year < t1.year?   as you want to know only films wher there exists no t2 whichs year is > t1s year

Comment: @Thomas, my select works as I've described, i.e return a movie if the same studio has no older movie with a higher rating.

Comment: Ah sry I thought it through from the other way round. tnx!

Comment: Sorry, for not replying earlier. I believe this answers my question and I accept it. Once again, sorry for taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work with RDBMS that support windowed function.

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, rn = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Studio ORDER BY Rating DESC)
   FROM #mytable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377418)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**For your original statement:**

```
select * from movietable where not exists (select 1 from movietable t2 where
movietable.studio = t2.studio and movietable.year < t2.year)
```

**For the second statement that django should be brought up:**

```
select * from movietable where not exists (select 1 from movietable t2 where
movietable.studio = t2.studio and movietable.year < t2.year
and movietable.rating <= t2.rating
)
```